# Calculation using expr in shell

Tags: shell

I have used the following code to Calculate simple intrest and its working fine

> intrest=$(( $p * $r * $t / 100 ))

However when i try to solve the above using `expr` it gives me error `expr: syntax error`

> intrest=`expr $p * $r * $t / 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `*`s.

```
intrest=`expr $p \* $r \* $t /100`
```

This has nothing to do with more than two variables.

```
intrest=`expr $p * $r`
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: @Rdx I'm glad it did.